# How can I reinstall the "read" command?

Tags: linux, read

About half hour before posting this, I ran the `autoclean` and `autoremove` commands.

A few minutes after running the commands, I ran a script that I've been using for months, there are no issues with it.

Upon running the script this time around, I was greeted by:

`"line 46: read: read error: 0: Resource temporarily unavailable"`

on a loop (the script runs within a `while` loop).

I was struggling to find the issue for about five minutes, and then I thought back to the `autoremove` and `autoclean` commands, and figure that they are almost certainly the cause of the problem, given that they're the only change I've made.

Given the nature of the commands, and the error message, I've come to the conclusion that the `read` command must have been removed.

I've implemented the `apt` command to reinstall all of the distro's core packages, in the hope that that reinstalls `read`, but failing that, is there a way to reinstall the `read` command on its own?

I've tried the obvious `apt install -y read`, but that didn't work, and I've had a look around, but despite searching specifically for "how to install read command", I'm just getting examples of how to *USE* the read command, hence the core reinstall and this question.

Thanks in advance for your advice :)

( Oh, and before you ask, I *have* tried turning it off and on again :D )

Comment: `read` is a builtin to the shell  Your problem isn't with a missing `read` command but with _what_ the command was trying to read from.

Comment: Please show line 46 of that script, and mayhap a little context... Where does stdin point to?

Comment: The error message means that some resource, such as RAM, is currently unavailable. I really can't see how you are connecting this with your `apt` commands. Since you're not actually telling us what your script is doing, I'm inclined to close this question as "unclear" unless it's updated with more information about your script (ideally, you would include the script in the question).

Answer (score 1):

The `read` is not a tool, it is a command, built-in into shell. It exists in all shells `bash`, `ksh`, `zsh` or even a classic `sh`. So you cannot uninstall it.

Check what the script is reading from. File? Stdin? Some pipe?

It could also be a temporary problem with the whatever gives an input stream, so restarting terminal or rebooting machine can help.

The only possible way for `apt autoremove` to break the `read` is if your shell is using some external library and that library was removed. In that case you would need to reinstall the shell (`apt update bash`). But it is not likely.

Comment: The script reads from Stdin. 

I tried rebooting the machine and restarting terminal before asking the question.

One thing I hadn't tried doing that's just come to mind is running the "--fix-missing" and "--fix-broken" options on apt. I'll let you know if those help.

Comment: @Lee Your issue has nothing to do with the apt autoremove or autoclean commands, but everything to do with your script, and you're not showing your script to us.

Comment: I found what was actually causing the issue in the end.

The follow-up can be found at:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/723384/what-is-the-problem-with-setterm-resize?noredirect=1#comment1371475_723384

Comment: “if your shell is using some external library and that library was removed” — if that were the case, `autoremove` wouldn’t remove the library.

Comment: @StephenKitt - as I said, "it is not likely". But it is possible, if chain of dependency was broken somehow. Imagine AppA installed from a box, it is using Lib1 and have it in dependency list. AppB also uses Lib1, but does not have it in its own dependency list, devs forgot to add it, but do not see a problem since AppA is always present. And years later - AppA switches to Lib2... What would happen to Lib1 and AppB in such scenario? And yes, I saw it in real life once.

Comment: I’ve seen such scenarios too, but they’re not possible in this instance — if AppB uses Lib1, the package building tools would ensure that it does have it in its dependency list.